# Cannot transfer variable values into dsolve?

Tags: matlab, dsolve

I got one question in matlab:

I get a value of c from other function, then I want to put c value 1 into dsolve to solve this differential equation. but the value cannot put into dsolve, what should I do to transfer value?
eg:

```
c = 1; 
u = dsolve('Du = 1+u^c','t') % c is c, but is not 1!
```

Comment: post your code, please

Comment: c = 1; u = dsolve('Du = 1+u^c','t')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your error is that when you use `'c'`, `c` is interpreted as a char (or string) and not a variable. What you could do is use [`num2str`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) to combine strings and variables, like this:

```
u = dsolve(['Du = 1+u^' num2str(c)],'t') % c is c, but is not 1!
u =
C16*exp(t) - 1
```

If you have several variables, you can do something like this:

```
u = dsolve(['Du = ' num2str(1/(m*n)) '*1 + u^' num2str(c)])
u =
C16*exp(t) - 1
```

Comment: thanks. but Im confused with the format, if i have more than 1 variable like u = u = dsolve('Du*m*n = 1+u^c','t') and m,n,c variables, how should i write?